# JavaScript not working Unexpected syntax error

Tags: discord, discord.js

I’m getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` When I run the script

> ```
>     client.on("message", (message) => {
> if(message.channel.type == "text" && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() == "suggestion"){
>     message.react("✅");
>     message.react("❌");
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code INEX07 wrote should word, you were missing `);` at the end of your code.

Your Code:

```
    client.on("message", (message) => {
if(message.channel.type == "text" && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() == "suggestion"){
    message.react("✅");
    message.react("❌");
}
```

INEX07 Code:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.channel.type == "text" && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() == "suggestion"){
        message.react("✅");
        message.react("❌");
    }
}); <-------- Here you were missing these
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.channel.type == "text" && message.channel.name.toLowerCase() == "suggestion"){
        message.react("✅");
        message.react("❌");
    }
});
```